# I'm seeing strange behavior in XNA when using MediaPlayer

Tags: xna, media-player

In XNA I'm using MediaPlayer to play my music.  I found that when playing the release build (run as the executable, not from Visual Studio) the game window would sometimes flicker and seem like it was trying to minimize and then come back.  Sometimes the game icon on the task bar will appear a bit to the side and slide back to where it is.  I'm using Windows 7. 
It was easy to reproduce by starting the game, making an explorer window the active window, leaving it for a second or two, then clicking on the game.  It takes about 6-10 seconds for the game window to twitch, but then it happens about every 4-8 seconds after that.

I hunted down what exactly was causing this, and it is the following code, being called through the main game update.

```
if (!IsActive && MediaPlayer.State != MediaState.Paused)
{
    MediaPlayer.Pause();
}
if (IsActive && MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Paused)
{
    MediaPlayer.Resume();
}
```

Basically, I'm pausing the music when the game isn't active, and unpausing when the game is active again.  For some reason this is messing things up. I've tried just muting the music instead of pausing but I get the same effect.  I made a new PC XNA 4.0 game, but even with only the above code (and the base.Update) in the main update function it still happens so it is definitely the code that's causing the problem.  Does anyone know what is going on here, or another way to pause the music when the game goes inactive?

Comment: Well I'm able to repro something similar at least. For me the game will actually hang and become unresponsive. Digging around it seems like this is an issue that has been around for a while. (see this thread form 2 years ago, http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/45296.aspx ) I'm still trying to figure out a good solution for getting around it and still getting the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce a similar issue (for me the Game window will actually hang and become unresponsive) in a new Game project using the code you posted above.

I was also able to find forum posts from others experiencing similar issues (from as long as two years ago like this one -> http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/45296.aspx ). This is apparently a bug in the framework.

I'm not exactly sure what might be going on. I'm guessing that there's some funkiness happening with checking the MediaPlayer which might be stealing window focus away and then coming back to the game which returns focus so that for split milliseconds the game is losing and gaining focus so the music is Pausing Resuming Pausing over and over again at 60 times per second. On weaker machines like mine it causes the window to become un-responsive. That's all just conjecture since I don't know for sure, but it makes sense.

I was able to work around the issue however by simply cutting the MediaPlayer state check out of the equation. If you have your own boolean flag that you add to the game (something like "isPlaying) and then query that boolean variable instead of checking the MediaPlayer state, the issue clears up and you get the functionality you desire.

The code would look something like below.

```
bool isMusicPlaying = false;
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    Song song = Content.Load<Song>("SampleSong");
    MediaPlayer.Play(song);
    isMusicPlaying = true;
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    if (!IsActive && isMusicPlaying == true)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Pause();
        isMusicPlaying = false;
    }
    else if (IsActive && isMusicPlaying == false)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Resume();
        isMusicPlaying = true;
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

With the above code you should still get the original functionality you were looking for while getting rid of the un-desired behavior that was occurring using MediaPlayer's built in state.

Comment: Works like a charm now.  Thank you.  You are an awesome person!

Comment: Just to tack on some more information, see my post in this thread: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/93734/561682.aspx#561682 . Basically, once the game window has lost focus at least one time, the internal MediaQueue class will frequently start taking an unreasonably large amount of time to return any result. This causes the Window to flash/hang because the UI thread gets backed up. The only workaround is to never ever access any of MediaPlayer's properties or fields since they all call into the internal MediaQueue.

Answer (score 1):

Why not pause the music in the events where you actually want to pause the music and resume the playback in the events that unpause the game? You then remove the need for a bool variable and to be checking it every time. I did that on my PauseScreen class logic.

Comment: What the code in my initial question is for is to silence the game when it's not the active window.  It's not up for me to decide when the player makes something else the active window.